# How can I disable option of "Download as Zip " on one of the branches from the REPOS for a specific usergroup/team

Tags: azure-devops, devops, azure-devops-server-2019

[image]

How can I disable option of "Download as Zip " on one of the branches from the REPOS for a specific usergroup /team, or if there is any alternative to that. [image]
This is how I have tried to solve but it's not helping.

Thanks
@Kevin Lu-MSFT

Answer (score 1):

> How can I disable option of “Download as Zip ” on one of the branches
> from the REPOS for a specific usergroup/team

For this issue, I am afraid this is currently not supported in azure devops. There is no option to disable "Download as Zip" in permission settings. Readers also have "Download as Zip" feature.

You could add your request for this feature on our [UserVoice](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion) site , which is our main forum for product suggestions. After suggest raised, you can vote and add your comments for this feedback. The product team would provide the updates if they view it.